# How to make an extension functions about getInteger for Context in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner of Kotlin, the Code A get a int value from resource file.

I hope to use an extension functions to do it, and invoke it just like `this.getInteger(R.integer.ActivityEditBackup)`

But Code B I made is incorrect, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
mContext.resources.getInteger(R.integer.ActivityEditBackup))
```

**Code B**

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity>Context.getInteger(int id): int {
    return T.resources.getInteger(id)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it a bit.

- You won't use the specific type of `Context` in any way, you don't need to make your extension generic.
- In the parameter list, the name of the parameter comes first, and the type after.
- The integer type's name in Kotlin is `Int`, with a capital `I`.
- You can refer to your `Context` inside the extension function with `this`.
- You can use support annotations to specify that your parameter is always an integer resource ID.

Overall, with these changes:

```
inline fun Context.getInteger(@IntegerRes id: Int): Int {
    return this.resources.getInteger(id)
}
```

There was also some general confusion about syntax, you should look into the documentation for [functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) and then [extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

---

Additionally, you can convert the function to an expression body and omit the explicit `this`:

```
inline fun Context.getInteger(@IntegerRes id: Int) = resources.getInteger(id)
```